# Fastest way to calculate pairwise comparison on 200k row MySQL database

Tags: python

I have 200k lists stored in a MySQL database.  Given a list A, I need to calculate a similarity score between A and each list X of the 200k lists.  Assume the similarity metric is something simple such as the length of the set intersection of A and X.

Given the nature of pairwise comparison, I couldn't think of a way to improve on O(N) for this, so improving the runtime means working with multiple CPU cores.  Right now I have this task split across 4 cores using multithreading.Pool(), but it still takes nearly 10 minutes to complete. Worse, my computer shuts down to protect itself.

For anyone who's dealt with this before, do you have an alternative method that you can share?

Comment: What do you mean "list"?

Comment: What is taking the most time? Getting data from the database? Actual calculations? If you're already using all cores for the calculation, there's no more CPU to use, so your only option is really to speed up the calculation, possibly by calculating some key metric that allows you to skip calculations if you already know the lists are too dissimilar.

Comment: FWIW, if you're using MySQL, the total work is likely to be IO bound.  This means that the Python computation steps aren't taking most of the time.  The FastestWay(tm) is to create a single SQL statement to do all the work and only return the better matching list.  In other words, the solution isn't really a Python problem ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def bestmatch(A, lists):
     a = set(A)
     return min(lists, key=lambda x:  len(set(x) & a)
```

Using *min* does the looping a C speed.  The *lambda* is a closure that references *a* quickly.  The `set(A)` step is computed only once, rather than in the inner-loop.

Comment: I'm accepting this because I think Raymond is on the right track when he suggested (comment to OP) that this should be reframed as a MySQL problem rather than Python problem. I think it was probably a mistake to try to do all of this in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your table of lists looks something like this

```
LISTID LISTITEM
1      1
1      2
1      3
2      2
2      4
2      5
```

and list A is eg. `[1,2]`, you could do it in SQL like this:

```
SELECT LISTID, COUNT(*)
FROM T
WHERE LISTITEM IN (1,2)
GROUP BY LISTID
```